# how to read a global javascript variable from actionscript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, externalinterface

Given that there is a global javascript variable on my web page named myVar, how can I access the value of the variable myVar from within my flash movie using javascript?

I see plenty of examples of using external interface in order to execute javascript from actionscript, but I am unable to find examples of returning values back into the flash movie using actionscript.

Thanks in advance. I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ExternalInterface works by allowing JavaScript to invoke an ActionScript function in the movie, and vice-versa. You can optionally receive a return value back from the invoked function. Here's a very simple example:

JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function getMyVar()
    {
        return myVar;
    }
</script>
```

Flash/AS:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
var result:string = ExternalInterface.call("getMyVar");
```

Comment: Nice, that's what I am trying to do right now, except I am passing the name of the variable to the getMyVar function and then returning this[myVarName]... I think this method is going to work.

Thanks!

Comment: This did in fact solve my problem. Here's what I used in javascript:

function returnVar(varName) {
     return this[varName];            
}

and in ActionScript 3:

var jsVariableValue = ExternalInterface.call("returnVar","jsVariableName");

Comment: Sounds like this could also work with AJAX and JSON for getting data to flash?

Comment: @jerebear, except that AS has functions for even broader data retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

You can also provide an anonymous function that returns your global variable value to the `ExternalInterface.call` method as follow:

```
ExternalInterface.call("function(){ return myGlobalVariable; }");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed Rex M's answer is a bit incomplete.

He was right about using...

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
var result:string = ExternalInterface.call("getMyVar");
```

Then in your javascript you can use

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }
</script>
```

However in order to use this, the flash movie must be in an html accessed over http. Not using file://

Here is a tutorial for communicating from actionscript to javascript and vice versa.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1a6CPPG-Og&feature=plcp

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("eval","getVar=function(obj){return obj}");
var yourVar:String = ExternalInterface.call("eval","getVar(JSvar)");
```