# CSS custom cursor on flash element?

Tags: css, flash, cursor

I'm trying to implement a custom image cursor in CSS, e.g.

```
cursor:url(/img/custom.png), pointer;
```

this works great, except when the mouse moves over a flash element (e.g. embedded youtube video). Then it reverts back to the standard mouse cursor. Is there a way to override this?

Comment: Flash is a plugin, so when your mouse is over a flash object it is not technically in the browser any more.

Comment: It could be done by hovering a transparent object over the flash... but that would disable clicking on the flash.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2529841/1411473)

Answer (score 1):

The best "solution" would probably be to include the custom cursor in the flash as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a perfect solution, [but this site](http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/toolbox/flashembed/onclick.html) suggests putting an empty div that loads the movie in when you click it (also helps initial page load time).

I'm not sure if it works, but [this site](http://progproblems.blogspot.com/2009/08/javascript-onclick-for-flash-embeded.html) says it has a way to have a javascript command activate. Might be more than you want, but I know the solution listed gets rid of flash objects seemingly infinite z-index (thus I know it can override part of it).